# how can I change the jenkins workspace path when using perforce?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I create a new project using perforce plugin, and it create a workspace on a default folder,I want to change it as I have already the workspace setup on my computer but I do not see any options to do so as I have read on a few threads that this should be on configure->advanced but I do not see any advanced tab anywhere. I have also read on several treads that the "Let Jenkins Create Workspace" should be not ticked but I am not able to find it, I attached a screenshot of the options tabs [jenkins options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xVe7.png)
And the main configuration tab, where the advanced button does not appear: [main configuration tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD4wy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on the right track. I believe the Advanced button you are looking for is at the bottom of the General section, just above the Source Code section.
[image: Advanced]